# php applications created on MS Windows may cause problems when running on Linux?

Tags: php

i'm new to PHP, developing scripts on Windows (WAMP)

Is there anything should i do before uploading files to Linux Server?

I use UTF-8 as charset. Does line-endings matters? Should i choose unix file ending when writing scripts on MS Windows?

Comment: Use linux directory separators, they work on Windows as well; and watch out for case-sensitivity in filenames

Comment: Try it and see. Come back here if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `linux` the directory separator is `/`.

In windows both `/` and `\` can be used.

`Linux` is case sensitive too. These are the two things to be noted.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in function and variable names , linux is case sensitive , Windows - not .
For example 
$test and $Test is same on windows , and various on linux system

Comment: That's not the case at all. In PHP function names and variable names are both case sensitive on both operating systems.

Comment: I think you mean that filenames are case sensitive on Linux but not on Windows.